# Firebase ML Kit for iOS: "Unable to convert data to a string using the detected encoding" error when using local model

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to use Firebase's ML Kit to label images. When using my local model (instead of a remote model), I get an error message when trying to process my images under the local model.

```
Firebase/MLKit][I-MLK017001] Error in parsing model manifest file (/Users/cameron.hamidi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/153A2576-4171-4DB2-9F0C-56A184E35EBF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/61817D0B-3B80-4FE3-BAE4-2EE5077938B0/TestVision.app/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite): Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to convert data to a string using the detected encoding. The data may be corrupt." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to a string using the detected encoding. The data may be corrupt.}
```

I have confirmed that the rest of my code works when using a remote model.

I've also confirmed that the `.tflite` model file, `labels.txt`, and `manifest.json` are all correctly in the Bundle. I've also used this model on a different Firebase/Xcode project and it worked there, albeit with a lot of cumbersome code that doesn't seem to be Firebase's recommended way to label images.

```
let initialConditions = ModelDownloadConditions(allowsCellularAccess: true,
                                                       allowsBackgroundDownloading: true)
        let updateConditions = ModelDownloadConditions(allowsCellularAccess: false,
                                                       allowsBackgroundDownloading: true)

        let localModel = LocalModel(name: "mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant", path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant", ofType: "tflite")!)
        ModelManager.modelManager().register(localModel)

        let images = getVisionImages() //Returns an array of UIImages to label
        let labelerOptions = VisionOnDeviceAutoMLImageLabelerOptions(remoteModelName: nil, localModelName: "mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant"
        )
        labelerOptions.confidenceThreshold = 0
        let labeler = Vision.vision().onDeviceAutoMLImageLabeler(options: labelerOptions) //this line is where I get the error

        images.forEach() { image in
            labeler.process(image) { labels, error in
                guard error == nil, let labels = labels else { return }
                print("\nnew image")
                labels.forEach() { label in
                    print("\n")
                    print(label.text)
                    print(label.entityID)
                    print(label.confidence)
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Do not write "solved" into the title please. If you have the answer, enter it into the Answer field and accept your own answer. Otherwise delete the question if it was trivially solved.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue. There were two problems: the first was that I should have used the `Bundle` path for the `manifest.json`, not for the `tflite` model file. So instead of
`let localModel = LocalModel(name: "mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant", path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant", ofType: "tflite")!)`
I should have put `let localModel = LocalModel(name: "model", path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "manifest", ofType: "json")!)`

The second was that I didn't check the contents of the `manifest.json` file, and the `modelFile` and `labelsFile` fields did not reference the correct files for this project.